# Highcharts title background can't be changed

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts to create some chart but I find it's not working for changing the `background` of a chart's title.

For instance:

```
  // works, the color did get to red
  title: {
    text: title,
    style: {"color":"#ff0000"}
  },

  // the color did get to white but the background is not set to red.
  title: {
    text: title,
    style: {"backgroundcolor":"#ff0000", "color":"#ffffff"}
  },
```

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857133/how-to-add-a-border-to-the-title-in-highcharts), you can do this by setting `useHTML: true` and using `background-color`.

```
title: {
  useHTML: true,
  style: {
    color: '#FF00FF',
    'background-color': '#000000',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nicholasduffy/a32vL38z/

Comment: Sadly doesn't export with the background colour